# directive in nested ui-view called twice

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

I'm using ui-router with components. The navigation is working great and the component $onInit is called once (as expected) but in the directive's $onInit (directive as element in component template) is being called twice.

If I remove the ui-view attribute from the components template it is only called once. Not sure why that is.

***First question***: should I be using ui-view in the way I am? I want to be able to have nested routes so the parent state is preserved (manage users will be a grid and I want to preserve any sorting, paging, etc). I also want the child routes to replace the parent's DOM fragment.

***Second question***: why is the directive's $onInit being called twice?

http://plnkr.co/edit/rc8vbt?p=preview

My code looks like this:

```
var admin = {
  name: 'admin',
  abstract: true,
  url: '/Admin',
  template: `<div ui-view=""></div>`
};
var adminManageUsers = {
  name: 'admin.manageUsers',
  url: '/Users',
  component: 'manageUsers'
};
var adminAddUser = {
  name: 'admin.manageUsers.add',
  url: '/Add',
  component: 'addUser'
};
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Admin/Users');
$stateProvider
  .state(admin)
  .state(adminManageUsers)
  .state(adminAddUser);
```

and the components

```
app.component('manageUsers', {
  template: `<div ui-view="">
    <div>Manage Users</div>
    <input type="button" value="Add User" ng-click="$muCtrl.addUser()" />
    <test-directive></test-directive>
  </div>`,
  controller: adminManageUsersComponentController,
  controllerAs: '$muCtrl'
});

app.component('addUser', {
  template: `<div ui-view="">
    <div>Add User</div>
    <input type="button" value="Manage Users" ng-click="$auCtrl.manageUsers()" />
  </div>`,
  controller: adminAddUserComponentController,
  controllerAs: '$auCtrl'
});
```

***EDIT***:
I created another plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PZnA5h?p=preview) that uses named views as detailed [here](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component) (Named views/View targeting).
Still the same issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that has been resolved in master and will most likely make it to the next release.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3224